# running a query inside a loop to do another loop

Tags: php, mysqli

Ok so what i am doing is getting member id's from 1 table and looping those ID's through another table to get values to output. I had it working going through the first loop, then notice the output was all screwy, so released I needed to loop it through again, since there will could be multiple entries in the 2nd query for MemID. now I put in the 2nd loop but its not even going through, not sure where I messed up the code, but doesn't seem to output now when running it through the 2nd loop. though it did output without the loop.  but that won't work due to multiple rows for each $memid.

```
$qry_skamembers = "SELECT * FROM ap_skamembers ORDER BY id";
$qry_skamembers = $mysqli->real_escape_string($qry_skamembers);
if($result_skamembers = $mysqli->query($qry_skamembers)){
    while($row_skamembers = $result_skamembers->fetch_array()){
        $AffID = $row_skamembers['AffID'];
        $MemID = $row_skamembers['MemberID'];

        $skacon = new mysqli(OW_DB_HOST, OW_DB_USER, OW_DB_PASSWORD, OW_DB_NAME);
        if ($skacon->connect_error) {
            die('Connect Error');
        }

        $get_data = "SELECT * FROM ow_base_billing_sale WHERE userID = $MemID AND status = 'delivered' ORDER BY id";
        $get_data = $skacon->real_escape_string($get_data);
        if($result_data = $skacon->query($get_data)){
            while($finish = $result_data->fetch_array()){
                $test = $finish['status'];
                if($test == 'delivered') {

                    $sale_amount = $finish['price'];
                    $product = $finish['transactionUId'];

                    $products = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM ap_earnings where product = $product"));
                    if(mysqli_num_rows($products) > 0) { }
                    else {
                        echo "AFF: " . $AffID . "  |  ";
                        echo "Mem: " . $MemID . "  |  ";
                        echo "PRICE: " . $sale_amount . "  |  ";
                        echo "PRODUCT: " . $product . "  --  ";
                        include('controller/record-sale.php');
                        echo "inserting record";
                        echo "run finished <br><br>";    
                    }    
                }
            }  
        }      
    }
}
```

I am still rather new at coding, so it might look a bit sloppy, my apologies for that.

Comment: Learn about prepared satements to prevent SQL injection

Comment: Do not escape the complete SQL sting.

Comment: What's going wrong is that in your second query you are not putting the value of the variable `$MemID` but litteraly the text `'$MemID'`. What Jens said though, learn prepared statements and that will also solve your problem I think. 
`"SELECT * FROM ow_base_billing_sale WHERE userID = " . $MemID . " AND status = 'delivered' ORDER BY id";`

Comment: surely you would be better using joins rather than multiple nested queries

Comment: @Teun that query seems to work fine - with the variable inside. that hasn't really been the issue, tested it and it outputs correctly.

Comment: @Teun - some information on that. http://www.hackingwithphp.com/9/4/5/mixing-in-php-variables --

Comment: @RickJones its not solved yet?

Comment: @IngusGraholskis nope still having an issue.. though its loading now. its just not giving any output.

Comment: @RickJones i see you output result only in else and else means if its == or less than a 0 is everything correct there?

Comment: the issue i am having right  now is this `
                    $products = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM ap_earnings where product = $product"));
                    if(mysqli_num_rows($products) > 0) { }
                    else {
                        
                        //include('controller/record-sale.php');
                        echo " ( Database Entry Complete ) ";
                         
                    } `  --  the output is still displaying the echo even when the product value is in the database.  thus its not finding it correctly?

Comment: @RickJones what happens if you echo $product ? also is transactionUId correct column?

Comment: yes trans is correct, and $product outputs correctly.. the $products is something i think is not going right..  sigh..  long day

Comment: @RickJones try to add $product like this in query '$product' or even '".$product."'

Comment: @IngusGraholskis '$product' fixed the issue

Comment: @RickJones i m glad that helped :)

Comment: @RickJones i edited my answer and if you feel like its deserve to be as accepted then go ahead and accept it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know if that is ist bu try to replace:

```
$get_data = $skacon-->real_escape_string($get_data);
```

with

```
$get_data = $skacon->real_escape_string($get_data);
```

i think there is an extra `-`

And as we found out in comments you need to change `$product`  to `'$product'`

Comment: yeah thnx that was an issue.

Comment: I am glad to help!

Answer (score 0):

You can do all that in one query,nevermind it will be much faster

```
SELECT aps.AffID,aps.MemberID,owb.price,owb.transactionUId 
FROM db1.ap_skamembers aps JOIN db2.ow_base_billing_sale owb
  ON aps.MemberID = owb.userID AND owb.status='delivered' 
JOIN  db3.ap_earnings ape 
  ON ape.product = owb.transactionUId  
ORDER BY aps.id
```

Comment: ap_skamembers and ow_base_billing_sale are on 2 completely different databases.

Comment: @RickJones Just specify the db in front of the table

Comment: ok yeah i see that, but you can't really make checks and such.. and i need the values for the include at the bottom to use for other information.